# How to add the Delimited Text Plugin for QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mac

I can't find the Delimited text Plugin- everything keeps telling me it's in the core build, but which core build? the Mac OS variant comes in multiple installers so without programatically unpacking all of those files to discover it where the hell is it? 
Can anyone please point me in the right direction, or post a link to the file; so that I can get it installed on my macs. 
Or alternatively state that the plugin is NOT available for the mac version [unhappy face]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Plugins" - "Manage Plugins" and enable "Add delimited text layer".

There is nothing to unpack/install.

Comment: Thank you, VERY much-I must have been inadvertently scrolling straight past it; or going slightly mad with impending deadlines